# Change value of textareas generated by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I have a dropdown:

```
<select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in getData()" ng-click="chooseStuff(0,dropdown)"></select>
```

Below i have a list of textareas:

```
<div ng-repeat="(controlKey,controlValue) in controlsList">
      <div ng-repeat="(labelKey,labelValue) in controlValue"> 
    <textarea ng-model="text1" ng-init="text1 = getContent(controlKey,labelKey)"></textarea> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This works good when I call the function on ng-click on the textarea.
What I would like to do though, is for every textarea to run the function getContent(controlKey,labelKey) every time the value in the dropdown changes. How should I approach this problem?

Thanks!

```
this.chooseStuff= function (dropdownNo, code) {
                dropdownCurrentCode[dropdownNo] = code;
            }
```

controlList and controlValue is just a dummy data (hardcoded json) in the controller.

```
 var controlsList = {
                "control":
                    {
                        "label": {
                            "en-US": "US label Value",
                            "en-GB": "GB label value"
                        },
                        "positivelabel": {
                            "en-US": "US positive label Value",,
                            "en-GB": "GB positive label value"
                        }
                    },
                "anotherControl":
                    {
                        "label": {
                            "en-US": "us value",
                            "en-GB": "gb value"
                        }
                    }

            };
```

Comment: Could you share controller code for `chooseStuff` and when do the `controlsList` and `controlValue` populate?

Comment: Added in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The solution was to bind the model to the function and add getterSetter ng-model option.

```
<textarea ng-model="getContent(controlKey,labelKey)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }></textarea>
```